# I don't feel like been his friend anymore because he always get angry when I tell him to changes his life style and repent toward Allah Azawajal

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu
I really want to ask about something that hurt my heart so much. Is about my childhood friend, me and him have been friend for more than 5 year's which means we always do many things together like having girlfriend, not praying in time even sometimes skip it.
So luckily we are separated for some times,I want to another town to attend my high school, so I met many people that always talk to me about my life and tell me to stop all what am doing and come back to Allah, Masha Allah I changed and repent toward Allah.
Now am back to my town, I found my friend still in all those wrong doing, I try to correct him but he told me that if his life is affecting me then I should stop talking to him.

Now my question, for me too I don't feel like been his friend anymore now so it that okay for both of us or what should I do?
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **"Surely you do not guide whomever you love, but Allah guides whomever**
> **He decides, and He knows best the ones (who are) rightly-guided."**

**-Quran 28:6**

From your story that you've mentioned, I can tell that your friend isn't a positive influence for you as a Muslim. You've mentioned how the both of you were astray from the path of Allah (SWT). From the above verse I've given you from the Quran, despite you trying to bring your friend back to the path of Allah, you are doing all you can I'm sure. Despite your efforts, he isn't the one listening, and it's safe to say that Allah is guiding him astray. And whomsoever Allah guides astray, no one can guide him back to the right path.

Your best effort if you're worried for your friend would be to make dua for him since obviously interacting with him in person isn't working out so well.
As Muslims, we should surround ourselves with righteous friends because on the Day of Judgement, the only friends you'll have are the ones who were conscious of Allah and reminded you of him and your deen. Not the ones you went out partying with.

We should also surround ourselves with friends who keep our remembrance of Allah and our deen high. It can be inferred that your friend had been surrounding himself with a lot of negativity and haram for him to be influenced as a person like this. Allah saved you from going astray, and from him telling you if you don't like the way he is to just not be friends with him, may be a sign from Allah to leave him. Which is best for you in this case. You've done all you can to try and bring your friend back, but unfortunately he's too far gone to go back to the path of Islam. If you really love him, make dua Allah guides him and Inshallah, he may come back to the straight path.

You should focus on befriending Muslims who give you positivity and make you remember Allah all the time so you don't have a repeat of your past. Repent, and change yourself as a Muslim because we only learn from our past mistakes.

May Allah guide us all and keep us on the straight path.

Ameen.

Comment: Masha Allah, thanks brother